# jquery set attr() input object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form application. I need to access an input object. I can not add this attribute.

i am getting error :

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'children' of object # is
>   not a function scripts.js:106 (anonymous function) scripts.js:106
>   x.event.dispatch jquery.js:4597 y.handle

elm[6].children() = Not null

t[0].value = Have a value.

```
$(".demo").delegate(".configuration .dropdown-menu button", "click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var t = $(this).parent().children();

    var elm = t.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().children().children();
    debugger;

    if (t[1].id == "Id") {
        elm[6].children().attr('id', t[0].value);
    }
})
```

I can see input object details. But i cannot add attribute..

Comment: Please replace `t.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent()` with `t.closest("selector")`.  Your JS is very brittle to the slightest HTML change.  Also, probably what you want is `t.closest("some selector").find("some other selector")` so you're not hard coding specific HTML positions into your JS.

Comment: absolutely right! the first that came to mind was this way. thank you for the suggestion. i'll try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `eq()` instead of brackets, as `[6]` accesses the underlying dom node in the array-like jQuery object, and then you no longer have a jQuery object that can be chained with jQuery methods etc

```
elm.eq(6).children().attr('id', t[0].value);
```

Note that the way you're doing this could potentially set the same ID to multiple elements, which is not valid.